# In Ruby, how to conditionally add several members to an object?

Tags: ruby

I would like to create a hash with several members added conditionally.
The simple approach is:

```
var a = {}
a['b'] = 5 if condition_b
a['c'] = 5 if condition_c
a['d'] = 5 if condition_d
```

Now, I would like to write a more idiomatic code. I am trying:

```
a = {
    b => (condition_b? 5 : null),
    c => (condition_c? 5 : null),
    d => (condition_d? 5 : null)
}
```

But now, `a.length` equals 3 whatever conditions are met. This is not the desired result.

Is there a handy solution?

Answer (score 1):

May be not exactly what you want but this can help

```
 array = ['b','c','d']  ##array of values you want as keys 
 a ={}
 array.each do |val|
   a[val] = 5 if send("condition_"+val.to_s)  #call method condition_#{key_name}
 end
```

If the conditions are not related you can use your own hash and you can

```
a = {
    b => (condition_b? 5 : nil),
    c => (condition_c? 5 : nil),
    d => (condition_d? 5 : nil)
}
a.values.compact.size
```

to get length of values other then nil

Comment: It doesn't help because in the real case the conditions are not related at all.

Comment: @viebel, you want length of hash to return size excluding nil , correct?

Comment: Thanks. What if you want `to_s` to skip the `null` values?

Comment: @viebel,can you be be a bit more clear what exactly you want?

Comment: I would like a.to_s not to display the keys whose values are null

Comment: @viebel, I recommend you adding another question for this or updating the question as per your latest requirement as such answers can be confusing to other readers.or else you can always have a good chat in chat room.

Answer (score 0):

How about you only add to the hash if the condition is met, like this:

```
a = {}
a.merge!({'b'=>5}) if condition_b
a.merge!({'c'=>5}) if condition_c
```

Comment: Calling `merge!` several times could be expensive

Answer (score -1):

In the second way, you're always going to have the three keys; the conditions only determine the particular values.  So if you want to use that syntax, you will need to define a custom method that only counts the keys if they are not nil (also, it's nil in Ruby, not null).  Something like:

```
def non_nil_length(hash)
  i = 0
  hash.each_pair do |k,v|
    if !v.nil?
      i += 1
    end
  end
  i
end
```

There's probably a better way to do that, but there's the quick and dirty.

Comment: This is not acceptable as I would like my hash to be usable by everyone!